# How can I submit a form placed in a page on click?

Tags: html, spring, email, controller, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring and Thyme leaf but I am trying to submit form on click.

I want to search for the Contact.html page, then after filling the form and clicking the button with the action "/send", the form to be submitted.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Contact")
public class EmailSender {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender sender;

@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processMail() throws Exception {

    try {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setTo("xx@gmail.com");
        helper.setText("xx");

        helper.setSubject("Hi!");

        sender.send(message);
        return "Contact";

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error in sending email: " + ex;
    }

}
```

So, if I do like this, I get error. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: so what is your error?

Comment: While submitting, your controller should POST (instead of GET). Where is your POST method?

Comment: the whitelabel error page. And if I remove the value = "/send", then the Contact page loads fine but the form is automatically submitted with no value in it, and cliking the send button does not do anything

Comment: It looks like, instead of @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST) you put @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET).

Comment: @AjayKumar Thanks! But I still get the same error...

Comment: Post your full error trace.

Comment: @AjayKumar Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 11 16:58:25 EEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: It means you are trying to access which doesnt exist. Do you have "Contact" (case sensitive) html/jsp in your project and have configured it properly? Or show full Controller code which has GET and POST for Contact Form (if any).

Comment: @AjayKumar Yes, and it is configured properly. See, if I remove the value = "/send", and just let the method = RequestMethod.GET/ method = RequestMethod.POST, then the Contact page loads fine but the form is automatically submitted with no value in it, and cliking the send button does not do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debug, this is the working code:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender sender;

@GetMapping("/send")
@RequestMapping
public String sendForm() {
    return "Contact";
}

@PostMapping(value="/send")
public String processForm() throws Exception {

    try {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setTo("xx@gmail.com");
        helper.setText("xx");

        helper.setSubject("xx");

        sender.send(message);
        return "Contact";

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error in sending email: " + ex;
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the advice and help!

Comment: Nice to see you got it working. I don't think that @RequestMapping is doing anything useful for you there.

Comment: Just let it there :)) All these annotations drove me crazy